# Return value from multithreaded process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing, worker

I've designed a function `diversify()` to take some expensive function `f()` and run it in parallel on all the cores of the machine it's being run on. I've also set this up so that if `f()` returns a value on one core, all the other threads are automatically killed. The code for that is below:

```js
let diversify = f => {
    // Split a function `f` into a thread for each core of the machine.
    // The first thread to finish will return its result and end all others.
    
    if ( cluster.isMaster ) {

        let children = []
        for ( let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
            children.push(cluster.fork())
        }

        cluster.on('message', (_, msg) => {

            if ( msg.cmd == 'stop' ) { children.forEach(child => {
                child.process.kill()
            })}

            return msg.out

        })

    } else {

        let out = f()
        process.send({ cmd: 'stop', out })

    }

}
```

The problem is that after one process tells the master process to stop through `msg.cmd = 'stop'`, there is no way to return the output `msg.out`. The way that it is being implemented in the code above, the `return msg.out` statement is inside an anonymous function nested inside the larger diversify function. Therefore, this return value is not exposed when you run something like `diversify(() => { return true })`, resulting in `undefined` instead. Is there any way to return what's being sent in `msg.out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending messages to workers is by design asynchronous.

There is technically no way to `return` a value from a callback that is an event handler, since the event may occur at any time.

The canonical solution to this problem is via [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Simply wrap the function body in a promise and `resolve` the value instead of returning it.

```js
const diversify = (f) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        // Split a function `f` into a thread for each core of the machine.
        // The first thread to finish will return its result and end all others.

        if (cluster.isMaster) {
            let children = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
                children.push(cluster.fork());
            }

            cluster.on('message', (_, msg) => {
                if (msg.cmd == 'stop') {
                    children.forEach((child) => {
                        child.process.kill();
                    });
                }
                resolve(msg.out);
            });
        } else {
            let out = f();
            process.send({ cmd: 'stop', out });
        }
    });
```

The result is then accessible in `out`:

```js
const getPid = () => {
    return process.pid;
};

diversify(() => {
    console.log(getPid());
    return true;
}).then((out) => {
    console.log(out); // true
});

// or using async/await

const diversifyAsync = async () => {
    const out = await diversify(() => {
        console.log(getPid());
        return true;
    });

    console.log(out); // true
};

diversifyAsync();
```